# What is a long-lasting and reliable battery for Dell Latitude D630?

Tags: battery, dell-latitude

The battery for my Dell latitude D630 (purchased in August 2007) is only holding charge for approximately 30 minutes. When purchased, it held charge for about 2 hours.

The Dell website sells two batteries for this laptop:

56 WHr 6-cell Lithium-Ion
http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Power/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=310-9080&mfgpid=190982&chassisid=8515

85 WHr 6-Cell Lithium-Ion
http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Power/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=310-9081&mfgpid=190782&chassisid=8515#Overview

Aside from a couple good reviews for the 56 WHr battery, both batteries have awful reviews saying that the battery works great for about a year and then completely dies right after the 1-year warranty runs out.

Can you recommend a third-party battery, or contradict the bad reviews on the Dell site? I am primarily concerned with longevity and capacity of the battery. In terms of capacity I am looking for at least 2 hours of battery power, preferably more.

Answer (score 2):

I am always reluctant to recommend any other battery than those approved by the manufacturer. Batteries are quite delicate and you may not want to end up with a potential fire hazard. If Dell (or other computer manufacturers) receive reports of problems with batteries from a certain batch they will replace the faulty battery, you wouldn't have this assurance from some "fly-by-night" battery reseller. Of course there is a price to pay for this security.

The life span of batteries depends largely on good treatment. I suggest to bookmark and read this website for tips how to treat your new battery:

> **[Battery University](http://www.batteryuniversity.com/)** is an on-line resource that provides
>   practical battery knowledge for
>   engineers, educators, students and
>   battery users alike.